# group consecutive values according to their distance

Tags: python

I have a list of number:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,14,23,45,46,47]
```

I would like to create a "python-structure" (I don't know exactly what to use) containing series for which the distance is less than 5

in this case I should have:

```
1,2,3
45,46,47
```

could you help me?

Comment: If `numbers = [1,2,3,7]` is the `7` part of the group?  It's within 5 of the number 3, but it's more than 5 away from the starting number of 1.  So does the 5 apply to the entire span between first and last or does it apply to the max difference between each number?

Comment: yes, 7 would be part of the group because it is within 5 starting from the previous number (3)..

Comment: I don't see how this is related to data frame, neither your input nor output looks like a data frame. Maybe you can explain a bit more.

Comment: @Psidom sorry...maybe data frame is not what I look for... I need a structure able to contain arrays of different lenght...

Comment: OK. so the numbers is sorted, and you want to split it based on adjacent difference?

Comment: can the nested lists have different lenght? if yes it is perfect

Comment: yes the array is sorted and yes I d like to split it based on adjacent difference

Comment: How about 14 and 23? Are they discarded for some reason?

Comment: they are discarded because 14-3 is > 5  and 23 - 14 is >5 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through numbers, check the difference and append the value to the results accordingly:

```
results = [[numbers[0]]]           # initialize the result with the first element of numbers
for x, y in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):         # use zip to get adjacent values
    if y - x < 5:
        results[-1].append(y)      # if difference is < 5 append result to the last sublist of result
    else:
        results.append([y])        # otherwise start a new sublist
​
results
# [[1, 2, 3], [14], [23], [45, 46, 47]]
```